# how to can i go over a file twice?

Tags: python, file, for-loop, iteration

I have the following code:

```
for line in AAA:   
    print line
for line_again in AAA:   
    print line_again
```

2nd print is empty.

How can I go over the list twice? How do I se tback the pointer?

Comment: Are you sure `AAA` is list? Most likely it is an iterator.

Comment: To see, try `print type(AAA)`

Comment: what do you mean by "2nd print is empty." what is the type of AAA?

Comment: AAA is a file i opened

Comment: A file is not a list.

Answer (score 0):

As others have commented you probably have an iterator, not a list; You can use [itertools.tee](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee) to get two *independent* iterators from same iterable:

```
>>> from itertools import tee
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> fst, snd = tee(iter(a))  # two copies of same iterator
>>>
>>> list(fst)  # exhaust the first iterator
[1, 2, 3]
>>> list(snd)  # now use the 2nd one
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: I do not want to create another list with a differant name - just want to move the pointer back and run the loop again

Comment: @NimrodB it does not create another list; it creates an independent iterators; iterators are not list

Comment: nonetheless - it's under a different name (I found the answer I needed - seek(0,0)  )

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
AAA.seek(0,0)
```

This will return the set the pointer back to the start.